# Android Bluetooth Service in Background?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I am new at the android programming. I want to build an app which can communicates to an arduino via bluetooth.

I started already and I have one activity where I can set up the connection und uphold it. It works pretty fine. For the connect and connected thread I wrote an own class which is called via an instanced verision in my activity.

But now comes the problem:
After I have successfully connected to my Arduino the current Activity (connecting) should stop and open a new Activity where I can start sending messages. 
But how can I send / receive data from the thread I created in the previous Activity?

I read something about Service etc.?
What is the best way to solve this?

When I have finished the app it should have many activities where I can communicate different data via Bluetooth. Therefore I want the first activity to set up the connection and then I can use it from the others.

public class blueTooth  {

```
private ConnectThread connection;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");



public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();

}

public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server
            // code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection


        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
            }
            return;
        }
        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (blueTooth.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
    manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}

public void manageConnectedSocket (BluetoothSocket socket) {
    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);

    mConnectedThread.start();
}

/** .................................*/
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                //mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                //        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
      }

    }


    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

}

}
```

Looking forward for your help!

Comment: Can you show up what you have already tried ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far because I do not know how to start. I can't think of any idead on how to talk to the existing thread from the new acitivity? The thread is still running after I close the first activity isn't it ?